# Problem with printing a product matrix using print

Tags: python, arrays, function, matrix

I have a matrix A and B and I want the product of both these matrices. Here's my code in python.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiplication(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:

    n, m_a = a.shape
    m_b, p = b.shape

    c = np.zeros((n, p))

    if m_a != m_b:
        raise ValueError('Dimensions of the Matrix A and B are not compatable.')
    else:
        for i in range(len(0, a.shape)):
            for j in range(len(0, a.shape[0])):
                for k in range(0, len(b.shape)):
                    c += a[i][j] * b[j][k]

                    print(c)
                    return c
```

But when I run the code, I get "Process finished with exit code 0" and not the matrix C. what could be wrong here?

Comment: `len` takes only one argument, the item to get the length of. You want to do: `range(len(a.shape))`. (Assuming that `len(a.shape)` is actually valid.) You should try printing out the values that you are using in your `for` loops before entering the loops.

Comment: Does the indentation of your last two lines match the actual Python code you're running?  It looks like the print and return statements is reached on the first iteration through the loop.

Comment: Going by the fact that n = row of A, m_a = columns of A, m_b = columns of B, p = rows of B, the for loops should be correct as they iterate over the required values, however could it be that there is a problem with ```c += a[i][j] * b[j][k]```?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do a dot product, if so, there is a buildin numpy function that does that for you.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiplication(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return a.dot(b)

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[2, 4], [6, 8]])

print (matrix_multiplication(a, b))
```

Or even shorter:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[2, 4], [6, 8]])

print (a.dot(b))
```

Comment: That was the first thing I did but then I tried doing it in pure python, without np.dot and np.matrix, to see if I can do it. Plus I'm downloading Visual Studios, so that I can install Numpy on Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiplication(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:

    n, m_a = a.shape
    m_b, p = b.shape

    c = np.zeros((n, p))

    if m_a != m_b:
        raise ValueError('Dimensions of the Matrix A and B are not compatable.')

    else:
        for i in range(a.shape[0]):
            for j in range(len(b[0])):
                for k in range(b.shape[0]):
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
    return c


a = np.array([[28,3], [3, 4],[8,9]])
b = np.array([[6, 4,7], [6, 8,9]])

print (matrix_multiplication(a, b))
```

Comment: Its works for a 2x2 matrix but for anything more, like a 3x2 and 2x3 matrix, I get the first 2 correct rows but the third one is always 0,0. Why is that?

Comment: seems your account has been deleted from stack overflow by moderators

Comment: try it once again